# php add key with value to array faster way

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have an array:

```
    $data = array(
        'loggedin' => false
    );
```

i want to add other keys as well their values if the user is logged in so i use:

```
    if ( $this->auth_model->loggedin()){//user is logged in
        $data["loggedin"] = true;//set to true
        $data["user_id"] = $this->session->userdata["uid"];//add new key with its value on $data array
    }
```

is this the best way to do it or should i use `array_push` and such?

Comment: Well, this is how you add values to an associative array. You can't really do this with `array_push()`. Also, speed does not really matter when you are adding two values to an almost empty array. Don't micro-optimize.

Comment: your solution is faster, with array_push you will call functions, this is a overhead.... see at http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to add overhead by calling a function (like array_push).

Yes. That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

With `array_push` you cannot set the key.

The way you have described is the fastest one.

You can create a second array with `user_id` key and then merge those two arrays, but this is not a good way to solve this case.

Stay with that you have right now.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you can use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to add values to an associative array, so it's ok to do as you are doing

Answer (score 1):

The way you are adding is better than using `array_push` (reason: you are inserting few values and it avoid the overhead of calling a function) if you are adding more values to this array, then you can use `array_push`.